# how can i confirm listview edit with a key?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have the following layout in a listview:

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr class="<%# If(Container.DisplayIndex Mod 2 = 0, "", "a") %>">
                    <td style="text-align: center;width:50px;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnConfirmar" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="../images/Aceptar.ico">
                        </asp:ImageButton>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;width:50px;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancelar" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="../images/Cancelar.ico">
                        </asp:ImageButton>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtZonaNombre" Text='<%#Convert.ToString(CType(Container.DataItem, KeyValuePair(Of Long, Mercurio.clsZonas)).Value.ZonaNombre)%>'
                            runat="server" Width="100%" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ZonaNombreValidador" ControlToValidate="txtZonaNombre"
                            Display="Dynamic" Text="La zona debe tener nombre" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

What I'd want is to confirm the edit by hitting the return key (intro, enter, chr(13), whatever you name it) and to cancel the edit by hitting esc key while the focus is on the txtZonaNombre textbox.

I've tried tu emulate a "click" using jquery, with this code:

```
$("#txtZonaNombre").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $("#btnConfirmar").trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
});
```

but the code isn't even fired (I've checked it with an alert call).

The whole listview is part of an user control (it's on a ascx file), and the control is inside a master-page layout (I'm referring to the jquery library from the master page), and the listview is inside an updatepanel.

I appreciate your help! regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id you set on a control is not the same as the id rendered in html (because ASP.NET prepends it with the id's of parent NamingContainers).

If you're using ASP.NET 2010 you can set the ControlIDMode to Static to ensure the id will be the same in the html.

Or, you could check what the id is in the html (view source in the browser) and change your JavaScript to use that instead.

Comment: thank you! knowing that the control name is not the one i set, i did a workaround. regards!